# Use HTML in java with existing variables

Tags: java, html, swing

I am trying to create a table within a JTextArea using the contents of a LinkedList. Right now I have:

```
for(int i = 0; i < commands.size(); i++) {
        String row = "<html><table><tr><td>"+commands.get(i)+"</td><td>"+desc.get(i)+"</td></tr></table></html>";
        MainConsole.console.textArea.append(row+"\n");
    }
```

However, when it compiles, it remains as plain text:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhgei.png)

Any tips on getting the table to display?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use a JEditorPane, you can set the content type to html: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I think there's a way to do this without explicitly setting the content type, but setting the content type certainly works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextArea is for displaying simple text, use JEditorPane for HTML text

```
public class TestJEditorPane {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
    pane.setContentType("text/html");
    pane.setText("<html><b>Hello World</b></html>");

    frame.add(pane);
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```